# Play 360° panorama video on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, fisheye

I just know a few about opengl es 2.0, like draw 2 triangle into 2 rect or a cube. But I have no idea how to handle this. a few about vertex and fragment, not much.

I shoot a video with 360 degree, How am I supposed to play video on iOS, the functions are: you can move your phone or drag one direction to another direction, so you can watch the video in different view.

The effect should be like Kolor Eyes.

I think the steps are:

1. get each frame from the video (original, looks like a sphere) [image]
2. handle frame one by one, to make it be view in panorama way to watch.

Hope somebody could help me out, Thanks a lot [image]

Comment: would you be able to share some code of the solution you implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not connected to ios or any other specific platform but first of all an algorithmic thing. How to convert the pixels from the pano view to a panaromic view? My best guess is something like a transfer function which takes pixel a at position A in the src image and transfers it into a corresponding pixel b at Position B in the destination image.

Maybe you should check the basics of texture mapping which is a common technique to map an image onto an arbitray surface.

Just as an idea: the source is a radial view ranging from 0° to 360°, so what you need is to transfer this into a view where the angle increases horizontally from 0° to 360°. Each src pixel would need an angle and a distance. Given these two properties you could write a function which puts this into a different view.